# How do I merge a free space of 30G in the logical drive into the D drive?

Tags: hardware, wubi

The 30G space was first created from D drive for installing Ubuntu(Wubi), and now I have already formatted the volume, and even deleted it, but the space is still there. What should I do to have that 30G merged to the D drive? I really need that 30G in D...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was wubi, there was no need to delete the partition. Right click on D: and click on `extend partition`. You can add the free space.

Comment: @xczzhh if it did work, please click the checkmark next to the answer to "accept" it.